# What is the proper syntax for the Less Than/Equal operator in MyBatis 3?

Tags: mybatis

How to use less than equal in MyBatis 3.

```
<select id="getLog" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.String">
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT * FROM TABLE1
        WHERE COL1 =#{COL1,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
        ORDER BY DATE DESC
    ) TABLE2
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
</select>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I show examples for the Greater Than/Equal Operator and the Less Than/Equal Operators:

```
ROWNUM &gt;= 20
ROWNUM &lt;= 20
```

Or, for readability, you can wrap them in CDATA

```
ROWNUM <![CDATA[ >= ]]> 20
ROWNUM <![CDATA[ <= ]]> 20
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither version is really readable, but personally I would prefer escaping them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CDATA` to escape "<" similar like xml.

```
  <select id="getLog" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.String">
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1
    WHERE COL1 =#{COL1,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    ORDER BY DATE DESC
) TABLE2
WHERE ROWNUM <![CDATA[ <= 20 ]]>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be only me, but I consider this to be more readable:

```
<select id="getLog" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="java.lang.String">
  <![CDATA[
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT * FROM TABLE1
        WHERE COL1 =]]> #{COL1,jdbcType=VARCHAR} <![CDATA[
        ORDER BY DATE DESC
    ) TABLE2
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 20
  ]]>
</select>
```

Notice that I had to escape the hash parameter, which admittedly makes it less readable. Yet, for queries that do not have parameters, this works pretty neat. The main advantage is that you can copy-paste the queries and test them in SQL directly.